# Why is no inbuilt route component available in react like in Vue.js or Ember.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I have really liked default routing library of Vue.js. But coming to react, I feel the official support is lacking for router library. I have used the third-party react-router library, but I don't know how reliable we can be in third-party libraries. I have googled, but everyone is so happy talking about how to use react-router and nobody seems to be bothered about not having an official router library. So I wonder why is no one concerned about this.

So, my question is, **are there any plans for releasing official router library with coming versions of React** or should we rely on third-party libraries?

Thanks for answering it.

Answer (score 0):

Despite react-router being de-facto standard for routing, you dont need to use it [unless you need to](http://jamesknelson.com/even-need-routing-library/). Use react-router to get all benefits from seamlessly interacting with `History` that covers everything it takes to manage location, history and URL in react-router.

As for absence of the standard lib: in my opinion there is no need for UI lib to be dependent on some standard router lib, it is clearly visible in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/), where you won't find anything regarding routes.

Comment: Cool, but I still think it would be great if react supports a default router. Just saying it.

Comment: "React is a declarative, efficient, and flexible JavaScript library for building user interfaces". Vue creator just created the default router lib for himself and project, whereas React maintainers let others impement routing the way they want, using popular libs like react-router or whatever.